# Nodejs JavaScript, Check if two different date formats are within 24 hours of each other

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to check if two dates are within 24 hours of each other but the formats appear to be different when I log them.

```
  static confirmPassword = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { newPassword, resetPasswordCode } = req.body;
    const account = await userModel.findOne({resetPasswordCode}).exec();
    if (!account) res.status(400).send({ message: 'You have not requested a reset' });

    console.log(account.resetSentAt); // 2019-09-17T04:07:18.634Z
    console.log(Date.now()); // 1568693738552

    res.status(200).send({ message: 'You already confirmed your password' });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns timestamp format, simply use `Date()` or `new Date()`. Maybe in this scenario it is better to use some 'time' library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) so you can find out exact time between two dates:

```
const date1 = moment(account.resetSentAt);
const date2 = moment()
result = date2.diff(date1, 'hours')
```

Comment: I also found without installing monet you can do `const hours = Math.floor((Date.now() - Date.parse(account.resetSentAt)) / 3600000);`